# Join two tables on different columns, where one column has the same data but inside quotations

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do a join on some data that exists between two tables. Each table has the data but in a different column, and one of them has it inside double quotes. For example Table 1 has columns

```
TABLE1
-----------
 RefID | Name
 --------------
 DR111 | John

TABLE2
----------
 DecID| #
 --------------
 "DR111" | 12345
```

how can I join the two tables on DR111 ignoring the double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix the data!  But, if you can't:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.decid = '"' || t1.recid || '"'
```

Comment: I wish I could fix the data! That works though thanks so much.